# How ot fix funciton according TS?

Tags: typescript

Here is a funciton:

```
function factoryTableView(category: number) {
    const views =  {
      1: new ImportExportTable()
    };

        return views[category];
}
```

I got this error message:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used to index type '{ 1: ImportExportTable; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type '{ 1: ImportExportTable; }'.
```

How to fix it?

Comment: What would you consider a "fix" here? What do you want to happen?

Comment: The keys of an object are always strings.

Comment: Probably it is key issue, so then convert category to string?

Comment: @Andreas irrelevant. TS is **not** complaining about that. Moreover, TS does consider `number` as a valid key type, to accommodate using indexes, e.g., arrays. Also, symbols are valid keys as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects implicitly have strings for their properties unless you specify otherwise.

Explicitly define a type for `views` if you want to use numbers for the property names.

```
function factoryTableView(category: number) {
    const views: Record<number, ImportExportTable> = {
        1: new ImportExportTable()
    };
    return views[category];
}
```

(They will still be strings in JS, but TypeScript will require that you use numbers to access them and they will be converted to strings only at runtime).

Comment: what if category is not presented in views?

Comment: "*Objects implicitly have strings for their properties unless you specify otherwise.*" that is ***not*** the problem here. TS is well equipped to consider numeric keys for objects. The error here says that `number` cannot be used to index the current  object, since the current object, only has a single key: `1`. Therefore, if `category` is `42` or `3.14` or `-7`, those are not existing keys. `category` is not a *subset* of the valid keys, it's a *superset*, thus includes values that are not valid. The `Record` type can be a red herring, it just masks the invalid key extraction.